# Monsters' creative origins?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, history-of-gaming

I can't read about Cloud Giants without thinking of "Jack and the Beanstalk", or Balors and Tolkien's Balrog, or Cyclops and Odysseus.

Has anyone compiled a list of 5e monsters and their creative/literary origins?

It's often helpful to RP a monster when you're familiar with the creative well(s) they were drawn from.

[edited] Okay - to limit this to a single creature, let's pick the Stone Giant. Their "dream" worldview is quite unusual and striking. If I needed to roleplay an important Stone Giant NPC at length, from what stories or other sources might I draw inspiration for its personality and story arc? Is this creature derived in any part from mythology? Or fiction? Or fable?  Or has it recently been brought to life in some well-developed episode of Critical Role? Or is it truly still just an empty sketch for us to fill out?

[...and if I'm in the wrong forum, don't hesitate to show me the door!]

Comment: I watched something on YouTube yesterday saying 'for inspiration go back to the roots' and my exact thought was 'how do you find the roots if you aren't already familiar' so this is a well timed question, if not a little broad. Maybe narrow it down to specific creatures you are interested in.

Comment: @SeriousBri "a little broad"? D&D Beyond has 76 pages of monster listing, at 20 monsters per page. This gives about one and a half thousand of monsters. Question about specific monster might be OK (possibly verges on the "authors intent"), but all of them? Definitely too much.

Comment: The issue with this question is not that it's 'too broad'. It isn't asking for an answer that addresses the origins of all 1,500 monsters on DnD Beyond (which would be too broad). It's actually asking if someone has already made such a list somewhere else - so it's a shopping question - which is also off topic.

Comment: @Molot SeriousBri is (apparently) English, where 'a little broad' means "OMFG that's a ***** huge question."

Comment: @richardb Oooooh. Sorry. Language barrier much, it seems ;)

Comment: Have you looked into the back of the PHB and the DMG on "inspirational reading" sources?  That might help you to refocus the question a bit, if it can be.  Appendix E, PHB.

Comment: @LouisWasserman [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Rather than just tacking on a modification at the end of your question, you should edit your question to stand as if it were always the best version of itself. Anyone interested in older versions can always view the revision history.

Comment: This is an old question, but I happened upon it and saw the asker tried to narrow it to Stone Giant. There are Stone Giants in *The Hobbit*. When the dwarves take shelter in the goblin cave, they are trying to get away from Stone Giants having a rock fight. While Gygax often stated his distaste for *Lord of the Rings*, he said that he enjoyed *The Hobbit* and read it aloud to his children, so this is possibly a direct inspiration for the monster.